# autocomplete does not get selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Number of autocomplete search box is dynamic based an #AddButton. Autocomplete is working, but when I select the values, it doesnt rendered it properly. Please tell me where Am I missing. 
Fiddle setup is at http://jsfiddle.net/jakenrush/kELm3/1/

Jquery code below

```
$(function() {
var projects = [
    {
        "label": "ajax",
        "value": "1003",
        "desc": "foriegn"
    },
    {
        "label": "jquery",
        "value": "1000",
        "desc": "dd"
    },
    {
        "label": "wordpress theme",
        "value": "1000",
        "desc": "h"
    },
    {
        "label": "xml",
        "value": "1000",
        "desc": "j"
    }];

$("#addButton");
var counter = 13;

$("#addButton").click(function() {
    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    var roleInput = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'Role',
        name: 'Role' + counter,
        id: 'project-description' + counter
    });

    var searchInput = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'search',
        name: 'search' + counter,
        id: 'project' + counter
    });

    var hidd = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'searchhid' + counter,
        id: 'project-id' + counter
    });


    newTextBoxDiv.append(roleInput).append(searchInput).append(hidd);
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    $("#project" + counter).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#project" + counter).val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#project" + counter).val(ui.item.label);
            $("#project-id" + counter).val(ui.item.value);
            $("#project-description" + counter).val(ui.item.value);
            $("#project-icon" + counter).attr("src", "images/" + ui.item.icon);
            return false;
        }
    })


    counter++;
});

});
```

html code :

```
<div id="project-label"></div>

<input type="hidden" id="project-id" />



 <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
 <div id="TextBoxDiv1" class="form-inline control-group">

 </div>
</div>
 <input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton' />
```

Answer (score 0):

i have update your fiddle and it is working, the problem is with your counter variable which never been incremented, because you have place at end of script, but you have return statement above it.

your fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/kELm3/6/

```
var counter = 0;
$("#addButton").click(function() {
    counter++;
```

Comment: But incrementing counter at first will not work with correct logic. Because, If u have added already 10 new rows, and if u start searching in the first autocomplete, the result will be rendered at the latest added row.